# Detailed analysis of the secretary problem

Tags: analytic-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The [secretary problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem) is well-known.  $N>2$ candidates present themselves for a job.  You must either hire a candidate immediately after interviewing him, or let him go.  The strategy you follow is to reject the first $R$ candidates, and then hire the first candidate who is better than all others you have interviewed so far.  The problem is to find the value of $R$ that maximizes the probability of hiring the best candidate, and the usual answer given is to reject $\frac Ne$ candidates.

In fact, one can show that the optimum number of candidates to reject is the greatest integer $R$ such that $$\sum_{k=R}^{N-1}\frac1k>1,$$ and that this number is always one of the two integers closest to $\frac Ne$. I'll defer the proofs of these assertions in order to get right to my question.

I guessed that the optimum value of $R$, which I'll call $R_N$ would be equal to $\left\lfloor\frac Ne\right\rfloor$ about half the time, but it seems that it's actually best about two-thirds of the time.  The graph below plots $$y_K=\frac1{K-2}\sum_{N=3}^K\left[R_N=\left\lfloor\frac Ne\right\rfloor\right],\ 100\leq K\leq1000$$ where $[\cdot]$ is the Iverson bracket:  $$[P]=\cases{1,& if $P$ is true\\0,& if $P$ is false}$$
[image]
While there's a lot of oscillation, it does seem as though $\lim_{K\to\infty}y_K$ may well exist, and it certainly seems that $\liminf_{K\to\infty}y_K>\frac12$.

I would like to investigate this, but I have no idea how to approach it.  It seems like numerical analysis of the harmonic numbers must enter into it, but how to pick out the fraction of times that the floor is better than the ceiling?

Can you give me any suggestions of what kind of techniques might apply and where to learn about them?  I put the analytic number theory tag on because I couldn't think of anything better.

Here are the easy proof of the facts stated earlier.

Suppose the best candidate is the $k$th interviewed.  Clearly, there is no chance of success unless $k>R$.  Then we succeed if and only if the best candidate among the first $k-1$ interviewed was one of the first $R$.  The probability of success is  $$w_R := \frac1N\sum_{k=R+1}^N\frac R{k-1}=\frac RN\sum_{k=R}^{N-1}\frac1{k}$$

Now $$\begin{align}
w_{R+1}-w_R&=\frac {R+1}N\sum_{k=R+1}^{N-1}\frac1{k}-\frac RN\sum_{k=R}^{N-1}\frac1{k}\\
&=\left(\frac{R+1}N-\frac RN\right)\sum_{k=R+1}^{N-1}\frac1k-\frac R{NR}\\
&=\frac1N\left(\sum_{R+1}^{N-1}\frac1k-1\right)
\end{align}$$
so that $w_{R+1}>w_R$ if and only if $\sum_{R+1}^{N-1}\frac1k>1$.  That is, the optimum number is of candidates to reject is the greatest integer $R$ such that $$\sum_R^{N-1}\frac1k>1.$$

(It is well-known that there are no positive integers $n>m$ such that $\sum_{k=m}^n\frac1k=1,$ so there is no ambiguity.)

Given $N$, let $R$ be determined as above.  I claim that $R$ is one of the two integers closest to $\frac Ne$. We have $$1<\sum_{k=R}^{N-1}\frac1k<\sum_{k=R}^{N-1}\int_{k-1}^k\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}=\int_{R-1}^{N-1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}=\ln{\frac{N-1}{R-1}}$$ so that $$R<1+\frac{N-1}{e}<1+\frac Ne.$$

Also, we have $$
1>\sum_{k=R+1}^{N-1}\frac1k>\sum_{k=R+1}^{N-1}\int_k^{k+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x=\int_{R+1}^N\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x= \ln{\frac N{R+1}}$$ so that
$$R>\frac Ne -1.$$

Comment: hi. this looks possibly interesting. is there any way you can start your post with a purely mathematical question and then give the context? or is your question actually about the secretary problem? i was a bit confused if it's about the secretary problem. if it is about the secretary problem, why can't I choose a candidate that is worse than one of the previous ones I've interviews; I feel like I should have that freedom...

Comment: @mathworker21 The secretary problem (or puzzle) is a well-known math problem.  The goal is to hire the best candidate, and the problem is to adopt a strategy that maximizes the probability of achieving that goal.

Comment: why is it that a strategy that maximizes the probability of achieving that goal one that insists that you hire someone better than everyone you have previously seen?

Comment: @mathworker21: If you hire someone worse than someone you've already seen, you're guaranteed not to be hiring the best candidate.  (Conversely, your only hope of hiring the best candidate is to hire someone better than everyone you've previously seen.)

Comment: @mjqxxxx by "converse", do you mean "contrapositive"?

Comment: @mathworker21 Well, if you hire someone who is not better than all the candidates you have seen so far, you have zero chance of success.

Comment: @mathworker21: No, I just mean it in the colloquial sense.... "conversely" meaning "from another point of view".

Answer (score 7):

Since the fractional part of $N/e$, calculated over the integers $N$, is uniformly distributed $\bmod 1$ (this can be checked by the [Weyl's criterion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Weyl%27s_criterion)), the result that $$\frac{N}{e}-1 <R<\frac{N}{e}+1$$ might suggest that $R=\lfloor N/e\rfloor$ and $R=\lceil N/e\rceil$ occur with equal probability.

However, as shown in the calculations of the OP, the correct result for the range of $R$ is

$$\frac{N}{e}-1 <R<\frac{N}{e}+1-\frac{1}{e}$$

The central value of this interval is $N/e-1/(2e)$, so the expected value of its fractional part is not $1/2$, but $1/2-1/(2e)$.

Assuming that the probabilities that $R=\lfloor N/e\rfloor$ and $R=\lceil N/e\rceil$ are linearly related to the closeness of this central value  with $\lfloor N/e\rfloor$ and $\lceil N/e\rceil$, we get that the expected proportion of cases where $R=\lfloor N/e\rfloor$ is

$$1-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2e}\right)
\approx 0.6839$$

in accordance with the observed experimental value shown in the plot of the OP.

---

After some constructive comments on the possibility to improve the bounds for $R$, the idea to calculate the integral between $k-1/2$ and $k+1/2$ gives interesting results and confirms the value above.

Since we have $$1<\sum_{k=R}^{N-1}\frac1k<\sum_{k=R}^{N-1}\int_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}=\int_{R-1/2}^{N-1/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}=\ln{\frac{N-1/2}{R-1/2}}$$ then $$R<\frac Ne +\frac 12-\frac 1{2e}$$

Also, since as $k\rightarrow \infty$ we have $$
1>\sum_{k=R+1}^{N-1}\frac1k>\sum_{k=R+1}^{N-1}\int_{k-1/2+\epsilon}^{k+1/2+\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x=\int_{R+1/2+\epsilon}^{N-1/2+\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x= \ln{\frac {N-1/2+\epsilon}{R+1/2+\epsilon}}$$ we get the asymptotic lower bound
$$R>\frac Ne -\frac 12-\frac 1{2e}$$

Collecting both results we finally have the optimized bounds

$$\frac Ne -\frac 12-\frac 1{2e}<R<\frac Ne +\frac 12-\frac 1{2e}$$

which numerically corresponds to the approximate interval

$$\frac Ne -0.6839<R<\frac Ne +0.3161 $$

Note that the interval identified by the bounds asymptotically converges to $1$.  Therefore, for any value of $N/e$, only one among $\lfloor N/e \rfloor$ and $\lceil N/e \rceil$ is a possible value of $R$, being included in the range.
Reminding the equidistribution $\bmod 1$ of $N/e$, we get that the probability that the floor function is selected is $$1/2+1/(2e)\approx 0.6839$$

Lastly, it should be noted that these bounds represent the best possible ones (otherwise there would be some $N$ for which no $R$ is allowed).

Comment: I thought about this, but it doesn't seem terribly convincing to me.  After all, these are rather sloppy bounds.  What reason is there, really, to believe that the midpoint truly represents the expected value?

Comment: What I'm saying is that there's nothing particularly special about those bounds except that they're easy to compute.  If I had used a more sophisticated analysis, I might have arrived at better bounds, with perhaps a different midpoint.  As far as the "linearly related" part, that is the crux.  This is the issue I was alluding to when I said, "but how to pick out the fraction of times that the floor is better than the ceiling?"

Comment: I agree with you that deeper analyses could probably give stricter bounds. In my opinion, this could be a good way to check whether the midpoint remains the same or not and whether the linearity assumption still holds. Another way to check the solution could be to increase $N$ in your plot.

Comment: An example of a better bound would be instead of using $1/k$ is strictly decreasing to say:
$$\frac{1}{k} < \int_{k-1}^{k}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}$$
Use convexity to say:
$$\frac{1}{k} < \int_{k-.5}^{k+.5}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}$$
This would give an upper bound on $R$ of:
$$R < .5 + \frac{N-.5}{e}$$
Which changes @Anatoly's answer to .760.  I think you're right we will have to assume uniformity over some interval, but first we need to figure out the exact rule determining whether to round up or down.

Comment: This is a very nice optimization of the upper bound. Interestingly, the same method can be used to improve the lower bound as well. In fact, while $$\frac 1k< \int_{k-0.5}^{k+0.5} \frac{dx}{x}$$ we also have, as $k \rightarrow \infty$, $$\frac 1k> \int_{k-0.5+\epsilon}^{k+0.5+\epsilon}\frac{dx}{x}$$ By the usual method, we finally get, as an asymptotic lower bound for $R$, $$\frac Ne -\frac 12  -\frac{1}{(2e)}$$ Note that, using the same method for the upper and lower bound, the midline is again at $ N/e-1/(2e)$ and the probability for the floor function is again $1/2+1/(2e) \approx 0.6839$.

Comment: I have just edited my answer according to the new optimized bounds.

Comment: @Anatoly: Very nice! The length of your bounds going to $1$ makes the rounding rule exact. The last thing to iron out is the fractional part of $N/e$ being uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ and then your proof is 100% rigorous. So, just cite [Weyl's Equidistribution Theorem](https://zhangyk8.github.io/teaching/file/Weyl_master_thesis.pdf) and you're done!  (Page 4 under Weyl's Criterion.)

Comment: Thank you, your idea of ​​optimizing the upper bound was fundamental to refine the proof.

Comment: No problem! I really like your solution because it gives an exact expression for $R_{N}$ when $N$ is large: 
$$R_N = \left\lceil \frac{N}{e} - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{(2e)} \right\rceil$$